# Counting problem involving Hat Check experiment with n hats

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is a spin on the [Hat Check problem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Hat-Check_Problem). "There are n= 2k hats (an even number). Find the probability of B = { $h_{i} = i$ if $i$ is even and $h_{i} \neq i$ if $i$ is odd)." My interpretation for what the problem is asking is to find the probability that at least one "even numbered" person gets their own hat back AND at least one "odd numbered" person does not get their own hat.

An earlier part asked to find A = {$h_{i} = i$ if $i$ is even} which, as I understood, needed to be rewritten as $ A = \bigcup_{i= 1}^k A'_{2i}$ where $A'_i = \{h_i = i\}$ in order to apply the inclusion exclusion principle.

Then $S_i = \dbinom{k}{i}\dfrac{(2k-i)!}{(2k)!} $

and $P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} (-1)^{n+1}\dbinom{k}{i}\dfrac{(2k-i)!}{(2k)!}$

I'm stuck on how to do something similar with the second conditional statement in the mix.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what the problem is. We will assume it goes as follows. We have $2k$ people, named $1$ to $2k$, who check their hats. The hats get scrambled. What is the probability that all even numbered people get their own hat, and no odd-numbered person gets her own hat?

There are $(2k)!$ equally likely permutations. The "favourables" are the permutations that fix the even numbers, and fix no odd number. The number of favourables is therefore the [*derangement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) number $D_k$, also known as $!k$.

Comment: Now that you mention it, is the event A = {$h_{i} = i$ if $i$ is even} ambiguous without saying either "for all i" or "for any i"?

Comment: My reading of it is that there is an implicit $\forall$.

Comment: @Bernabe, the $h_i \ne i$ if $i$ is odd is equally ambiguous.